# Why this simple code of bootstrap cause horizontal scroll?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie to bootstrap, I'm trying to build a 3 column media object with it but my code cause  scrolls horizontally:
this is my js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5ea98ytm/
and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Example1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/140x140" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <! MEDIA LEFT -->
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4> some texts
                    </div>
                    <! MEDIA BODY -->
                </div>
                <! MEDIA  -->

            </div>
            <! CONTAINER -->
        </div>
        <! COL-MD-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/140x140" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <! MEDIA LEFT -->
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4> some texts
                    </div>
                    <! MEDIA BODY -->
                </div>
                <! MEDIA  -->

            </div>
            <! CONTAINER -->
        </div>
        <! COL-MD-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/140x140" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <! MEDIA LEFT -->
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4> some texts
                    </div>
                    <! MEDIA BODY -->
                </div>
                <! MEDIA  -->

            </div>
            <! CONTAINER -->
        </div>
        <! COL-MD-4 -->
    </div>
  </div>
<! ROW -->
</div>
  <! C-F -->
    <script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm just trying to create 3 column of media object with col-md-4 Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I hardly found scrolling in the fiddle you mentioned. Be clear on what you are posting. Did not exactly understand what you need!

Comment: there is no problem in small devices(that is defualt show on fiddle) but if your device  width is bigger than 990px you see horizontally scroll

Answer (score 3):

Remove all containers above media class object. Bcoz it takes the whole width of the page. In my pc width: 1170px;

Comment: You get it correctly in small sizes because it takes col-xs-12 and col-md-12. So it takes full width of the row.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           </head><body>
           <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/140x140" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- MEDIA LEFT -->
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4> some texts
                    </div>
                    <!-- MEDIA BODY -->
                </div>
                <!-- MEDIA  -->

          
            <!-- CONTAINER -->
        </div>
        <!-- COL-MD-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
         
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/140x140" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- MEDIA LEFT -->
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4> some texts
                    </div>
                    <!-- MEDIA BODY -->
                </div>
                <!-- MEDIA  -->

           
            <!-- CONTAINER -->
        </div>
        <!-- COL-MD-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/140x140" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- MEDIA LEFT -->
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4> some texts
                    </div>
                    <!-- MEDIA BODY -->
                </div>
                <!-- MEDIA  -->

        
            <!-- CONTAINER -->
        </div>
        <!-- COL-MD-4 -->
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- ROW -->
</div>
           </body>
           </html>
```

Remove the `<div class="container>` from all media objects. It is causing problems.

Comment: thanks, but why container class causing this problem?

Comment: @JordanBos as the container takes the width of the viewport i.e the width of the device screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is on larger screen , it is showing horizontal scroll, then use overflow-x:hidden in body tag.
See like that:

```
<body style="overflow-x:hidden;">

/// all code stuffs


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the screen resolution .col-md-4 will work for the Laptops and desktops, it will not work for the smaller devices you have to give .col-sm-* (in place of * the size you have to give)

```
       <div class="col-md-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

replace this with

```
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
```